# docker error when using log-driver="syslog" on OS X

Tags: docker, osx-yosemite, syslog, boot2docker

docker error when using `--log-driver="syslog"` on OS X

I am trying to learn how to use `docker` containers on OS X (10.10.3), I understand the differences with the standard Linux implementation ( need boot2docker VM) and I wonder if there is any impact on the way I can log messages with syslog

when I start a container with the `--log-driver="syslog"` option, the container is created but  I get an error upon start

```
~$ docker run --log-driver="syslog" --name daemon_dwayne -d ubuntu /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo hello_world; sleep 2; done;"
1f623793049916d5c....
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 1f623793049916d5....: Unix syslog delivery error
```

this is running fine on a Linux machine...  thanks for any hint

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Boot2docker runs in a small linux VM. By default, syslog isn't running in the VM. You can turn it on by running syslogd in the VM e.g:

```
$ boot2docker ssh
...
docker@boot2docker:~$ syslogd
```

If you then try running your container again it should work.

You can make this change permanent by calling syslogd from the file `/var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh` inside the boot2docker VM, which boot2docker will execute before starting Docker.

Comment: thanks a lot...  "By default, syslog isn't running in the VM"   forget to check it !!!

Comment: and in boot2docker vm, the syslog output is attached to `/var/log/messages`

Comment: do you know how to link the syslog output to something else than /var/log/messages. I tried to use a configuration file /etc/syslog.conf but it looks like it's not working. Any idea ?